# Smaller gap between two legends in one plot (e.g. color and size scale)

Tags: r, ggplot2

how do I reduce the gap between two guides in one plot. In the example below, the two guides are from a color and size scale and I want to change the gap between the two so that the title 'size' is right below the legend-point for 1. Design-wise, it might not make sense in this example but in my actual application it does.

```
df=data.frame(x=rnorm(100),y=rnorm(100),color=factor(rbinom(100,1,0.5)),size=runif(100))
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y,color=color,size=size)) + geom_point()
```

Edit: Here is the plot. I would like to make the gap highlighted by the green line and the arrow smaller.

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about what are called 'scales' in both lattice and ggplot terminology, or are your referring to 'legends'?

Comment: I am talking about the legends on the left pf the plot called 'color' and 'size' in the example plot. I want to move to two closer together.

Comment: you define the problem better, but possible duplicate?  :/  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11366964/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-spacing-between-legend-items-in-ggplot2

Comment: @AnthonyDamico no it is not a duplicate.

Comment: @Anthony, I think your linked thread is about the spacing between the legend keys (the keys for `0' and `1' color legend in the example). My question is about the spacing between two legends as indicated with the green arrow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried to play to customize `legend` or `guide` parameters but I can't find a solution. I hope give a solution using ggplot2 settings.

Here 2 solutions based on the `gtable` and `grid` packages.

for the `gtable` solution, the code is inspired from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13426470/justification-of-multiple-legends-in-ggmap-ggplot2).

[image]

```
  library(gtable)
  # Data transformation
  data <- ggplot_build(p)
  gtable <- ggplot_gtable(data)
  # Determining index of legends table
  lbox <- which(sapply(gtable$grobs, paste) == "gtable[guide-box]")
  # changing the space between the 2 legends: here -0.5 lines
  guide <- gtable$grobs[[lbox]]
  gtable$grobs[[lbox]]$heights <- unit.c(guide$heights[1:2],
                                    unit(-.5,'lines'),  ## you can the GAP here
                                    guide$heights[4:5])
  # Plotting
  grid.draw(gtable)
```

Similar using the `grid` package ( we redraw in the viewport of the legend)

```
pp <- grid.get('guide',grep=T)
 depth <- downViewport(pp$wrapvp$name)
 guide <- grid.get('guide',grep=T)
 grid.rect(gp=gpar(fill='white'))
 guide$heights <- unit.c(guide$heights[1:2],unit(-0.2,'lines'),guide$heights[4],unit(0.1,'lines'))
 grid.draw(guide)
 upViewport(depth)
```

Comment: Thanks, I know that. My question is whether there is an option to move the two guides/two legends for the size and the color scale closer together.

Comment: @user1318686 What if you append your answer with a picture to show your final output?

Comment: Done. I would like to make the gap highlighted by the green line and the arrow smaller.

Comment: I still don't see a small gap between two legends. Did you miss something?

Comment: Thanks! That seems to be a good approach to make the gap larger but I don't see how I can use it to make the gap smaller.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I show it just for demonstration. I don't know how much gap he wants. I will update my answer. I need to guess what the OP want each time!

Comment: Yes, I get that idea and I see how it makes the gap bigger. row=3 makes it smaller compared to row=5 but it's still bigger compared to original plot, which corresponds to row=2. My goal is to make it smaller and row=1 obviously has a different effect.

Comment: @user1318686  For some reasons I understand you want bigger gap not smaller one! In update my solution now, hope that help.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks! One small suggestion for an edit: The `gtable` based solution also requires the guide object, which is only defined in the `grid` based solution. I think it would be good to add `guide <- grid.get('guide',grep=T)` to the first solution (it the line only works after plotting, right?) so that the code runs by itself.

Comment: @user1318686! yes I forget to clean my workspace! I update my answer!  without using the grid package.

Comment: @agstudy If we remove the two tittles of legend, how to set the gap between the two legends to 0? I mean merging the two legends into one. Thank you  in advance!

Answer (score 43):

Now it seems to be possible using the theme parameters:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y,color=color,size=size)) + geom_point() + 
theme(legend.spacing.y = unit(-0.5, "cm"))
```

You can also try to decrease margins of the legends:

```
legend.margin = margin(-0.5,0,0,0, unit="cm")
```

or older

```
legend.margin=unit(0, "cm")
```