# Merging 2 Legends In a Specific way

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have a plot of my data that includes both a boxplot and a point plot (data from mtcars for illustration)

```
ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=factor(cyl), y=mpg), fill=factor(carb),shape=factor(vs))+
     geom_boxplot(data=subset(mtcars,am==1),aes(x = factor(cyl), y = mpg,fill=factor(carb),shape=factor(vs)),outlier.shape = NA, alpha = 0.85, width = .65, colour = "BLACK") +
      geom_point(data=subset(mtcars,am==1 & vs==1),aes(x = factor(cyl), y = mpg,fill=factor(carb),shape=factor(vs)),outlier.shape = NA,size=5,alpha=.4,shape=1, colour = "BLACK", position = position_dodge(width = 0.65))
```

my objective is for there

1. to be a single legend instead of two legends
2. that now shows all the colors associated with the fill (based on carb) and a single element which explains what the open circles correspond to (i.e. vs==1).
3. for that single element (that corresponds to geom_point) to display an open circle (corresponding to the open circle in the graph) and not boxplots as its currently showing.

any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Add `scale_shape_manual(name = "vs", values = 1)` to have the point legend become a circle. As for merging the two legends, I don't believe that's possible without hacking the `ggplot` object, `carb` has 5 levels and `vs` only 2.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the shape aesthetic from geom_boxplot. Also, in general no need to specify color = "black", as this is the default for geom_boxplot (same for geom_point).

The version I was running online threw a warning regarding `outlier.shape`, so I have removed that.

Add shape as constant aesthetic to point and use `scale_shape_manual` to define your shape (use shape = 21 if you want a fill - your code suggests this, or shape = 1, if you don’t.). When you remove the legend title, the legends look fairly "merged".

However, Not sure what you exactly mean with "merged legend" . Mind showing a desired output?

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=factor(cyl), y=mpg), fill=factor(carb),shape=factor(vs))+
  geom_boxplot(data=subset(mtcars,am==1), aes(x = factor(cyl), y = mpg, fill=factor(carb)), alpha = 0.85, width = .65) +
  geom_point(data=subset(mtcars,am==1 & vs==1),aes(x = factor(cyl), y = mpg,fill=factor(carb), shape = "v = 1"), size=5, alpha=.4, position = position_dodge(width = 0.65)) +
  scale_shape_manual(NULL, values = 21)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your suggestion! is there any way to make the v=1 right below the factor(carb)?

Comment: @user15791858 yes - check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14103920/smaller-gap-between-two-legends-in-one-plot-e-g-color-and-size-scale