# How can I make consistent-width plots in ggplot (with legends)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've got a few different categories that I want to plot.  These are *different* categories, each with their own set of labels, but which makes sense to group together in the document.  The following gives some simple stacked bar chart examples:

```
df <- data.frame(x=c("a", "b", "c"),
                 y=c("happy", "sad", "ambivalent about life"))
ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(0), fill=x)) + geom_bar()
ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(0), fill=y)) + geom_bar()
```

The problem is that with different labels, the legends have different widths, which means the plots have different widths, leading to things looking a bit goofy if I make a table or `\subfigure` elements.  How can I fix this?

Is there a way to explicitly set the width (absolute or relative) of either the plot or the legend?

[image: Chart 1 based on x (wider)]
[image: Chart 2 based on y (narrower)]

Comment: another alternative: you could probably place the legends at the top/bottom/inside the plot?

Comment: `+ theme(legend.position = "top")` (or "bottom") (or) `+ theme(legend.position=c(1,0), legend.justification=c(1,0))`

Answer (score 49, accepted):

**Edit:**  Very easy with `egg` package

```
# install.packages("egg")

library(egg)

p1 <- ggplot(data.frame(x=c("a","b","c"),
                        y=c("happy","sad","ambivalent about life")),
             aes(x=factor(0),fill=x)) + 
      geom_bar()
p2 <- ggplot(data.frame(x=c("a","b","c"),
                        y=c("happy","sad","ambivalent about life")),
             aes(x=factor(0),fill=y)) + 
      geom_bar()

ggarrange(p1,p2, ncol = 1)
```

**Original** Udated to ggplot2 2.2.1

Here's a solution that uses functions from the `gtable` package, and focuses on the widths of the legend boxes. (A  more general solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34797443/arrange-common-plot-width-with-facetted-ggplot-2-0-0-gridextra/35837133#35837133).)

```
library(ggplot2)   
library(gtable)    
library(grid)
library(gridExtra) 

# Your plots
p1 <- ggplot(data.frame(x=c("a","b","c"),y=c("happy","sad","ambivalent about life")),aes(x=factor(0),fill=x)) + geom_bar()
p2 <- ggplot(data.frame(x=c("a","b","c"),y=c("happy","sad","ambivalent about life")),aes(x=factor(0),fill=y)) + geom_bar()

# Get the gtables
gA <- ggplotGrob(p1)
gB <- ggplotGrob(p2)

# Set the widths
gA$widths <- gB$widths

# Arrange the two charts.
# The legend boxes are centered
grid.newpage()
grid.arrange(gA, gB, nrow = 2)
```

If in addition, the legend boxes need to be left justified, and borrowing some code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13426470/justification-of-multiple-legends-in-ggmap-ggplot2) written by @Julius

```
p1 <- ggplot(data.frame(x=c("a","b","c"),y=c("happy","sad","ambivalent about life")),aes(x=factor(0),fill=x)) + geom_bar()
p2 <- ggplot(data.frame(x=c("a","b","c"),y=c("happy","sad","ambivalent about life")),aes(x=factor(0),fill=y)) + geom_bar()

# Get the widths
gA <- ggplotGrob(p1)
gB <- ggplotGrob(p2)

# The parts that differs in width
leg1 <- convertX(sum(with(gA$grobs[[15]], grobs[[1]]$widths)), "mm")
leg2 <- convertX(sum(with(gB$grobs[[15]], grobs[[1]]$widths)), "mm")

# Set the widths
gA$widths <- gB$widths

# Add an empty column of "abs(diff(widths)) mm" width on the right of 
# legend box for gA (the smaller legend box)
gA$grobs[[15]] <- gtable_add_cols(gA$grobs[[15]], unit(abs(diff(c(leg1, leg2))), "mm"))

# Arrange the two charts
grid.newpage()
grid.arrange(gA, gB, nrow = 2)
```

[image]

**Alternative solutions**  There are `rbind` and `cbind` functions in the `gtable` package for combining grobs into one grob. For the charts here, the widths should be set using `size = "max"`, but the CRAN version of `gtable` throws an error.

One option: It should be obvious that the legend in the second plot is wider. Therefore, use the `size = "last"` option.

```
# Get the grobs
gA <- ggplotGrob(p1)
gB <- ggplotGrob(p2)

# Combine the plots
g = rbind(gA, gB, size = "last")

# Draw it
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

Left-aligned legends:

```
# Get the grobs
gA <- ggplotGrob(p1)
gB <- ggplotGrob(p2)

# The parts that differs in width
leg1 <- convertX(sum(with(gA$grobs[[15]], grobs[[1]]$widths)), "mm")
leg2 <- convertX(sum(with(gB$grobs[[15]], grobs[[1]]$widths)), "mm")

# Add an empty column of "abs(diff(widths)) mm" width on the right of 
# legend box for gA (the smaller legend box)
gA$grobs[[15]] <- gtable_add_cols(gA$grobs[[15]], unit(abs(diff(c(leg1, leg2))), "mm"))

# Combine the plots
g = rbind(gA, gB, size = "last")

# Draw it
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

A second option is to use `rbind` from Baptiste's `gridExtra` package

```
# Get the grobs
gA <- ggplotGrob(p1)
gB <- ggplotGrob(p2)

# Combine the plots
g = gridExtra::rbind.gtable(gA, gB, size = "max")

# Draw it
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

Left-aligned legends:

```
# Get the grobs
gA <- ggplotGrob(p1)
gB <- ggplotGrob(p2)

# The parts that differs in width
leg1 <- convertX(sum(with(gA$grobs[[15]], grobs[[1]]$widths)), "mm")
leg2 <- convertX(sum(with(gB$grobs[[15]], grobs[[1]]$widths)), "mm")

# Add an empty column of "abs(diff(widths)) mm" width on the right of 
# legend box for gA (the smaller legend box)
gA$grobs[[15]] <- gtable_add_cols(gA$grobs[[15]], unit(abs(diff(c(leg1, leg2))), "mm"))

# Combine the plots
g = gridExtra::rbind.gtable(gA, gB, size = "max")

# Draw it
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

Comment: That's excellent!  Are these functions and variables documented anywhere or did you just look through the `ggplot` source?

Comment: @jamie.f.olson There is the [gtable manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gtable/index.html) on CRAN, but other than that, it's a matter of taking note of others' examples on SO and sometimes on the [ggplot mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups#!forum/ggplot2).

Comment: Did you try `rbind()`ing the plots together? That should just work, but I can't remember if we finished that code.

Comment: I seem to run into the issue @baptiste mentions with units when using `rbind`

Comment: Is this method still the best way to align legend boxes or are there any new functions to aid with this?  It seems like a lot of manual work to do this very often.

Comment: Not sure. I can't check, but if you follow the link to the "more general solution", but look to baptists's solution. You might find something useful in baptise's `egg` package.

Comment: In order to install egg I had to do 
install.packages("digest")
install.packages("devtools")
library(digest)
devtools::install_github("baptiste/egg")
library(egg)

Answer (score 17):

The `cowplot` package also has the `align_plots` function for this purpose (output not shown),

```
both2 <- align_plots(p1, p2, align="hv", axis="tblr")
p1x <- ggdraw(both2[[1]])
p2x <- ggdraw(both2[[2]])
save_plot("cow1.png", p1x)
save_plot("cow2.png", p2x)
```

and also `plot_grid` which saves the plots to the same file.

```
library(cowplot)
both <- plot_grid(p1, p2, ncol=1, labels = c("A", "B"), align = "v")
save_plot("cow.png", both)
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

As @hadley suggests, `rbind.gtable` should be able to handle this,

```
  grid.draw(rbind(ggplotGrob(p1), ggplotGrob(p2), size="last"))
```

however, the layout widths should ideally be `size="max"`, which [doesn't cope well](https://github.com/hadley/gtable/pull/15) with some types of grid units.

Comment: Is:
    `Error in mmm < each : comparison of these types is not implemented`

what you mean?  I didn't see an example of the error message on the issue page.

Answer (score 4):

Just by chance, I noticed that Arun's solution he had suggested in his comments hasn't been picked up. I feel his simple and efficient approach is really worth to be illustrated.

Arun suggested to move the legend to the top or bottom:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(0), fill=x)) + geom_bar() + theme(legend.position = "bottom")
ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(0), fill=y)) + geom_bar() + theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]
[image]

**Now, the plots have the same width as requested.** In addition, the plot area is equally sized in both cases.

If there are more factors or even longer labels, it might become necessary to play around with the legend, e.g., to display the legend in two ore more rows. `theme()` and `guide_legend()` have several parameters to control the position and appearance of legends in `ggplot2`.

Answer (score 2):

I created a little function based on the answer of @Sandy.

```r
same.size.ggplot <- function(vector.string.graph, # a vector of strings which correspond to Robject ggplot graphs
                             reference.string.graph, # a string of a  Robject ggplot graphs where height and/or height will be taken for reference
                             width = T, # if you wanna adapat only the width
                             height = F # if you wanna adapat only the height
) {

  # example: same.size.ggplot(p0rep(c("a", "b"), thre), "a30") 


  which(vector.string.graph %in% reference.string.graph)

  newref <- ggplotGrob(get(reference.string.graph))
  ref.width <- newref$widths
  ref.height <- newref$heights

  assign(reference.string.graph, newref, env = parent.frame(1))

  for(i in seq_along(vector.string.graph)) {
    if(vector.string.graph[i] != reference.string.graph) {
      new <- ggplotGrob(get(vector.string.graph[i]))
      if( width ) {
        new$widths <- ref.width
      }
      if( height ) {
        new$heights <- ref.height
      }
      assign(vector.string.graph[i], new, env = parent.frame(1))
    }
  }
}
```

```r
p1 <- ggplot(data.frame(x=c("a","b","c"),y=c("happy","sad","ambivalent about life")),aes(x=factor(0),fill=x)) + geom_bar()
p2 <- ggplot(data.frame(x=c("a","b","c"),y=c("happy","sad","ambivalent about life")),aes(x=factor(0),fill=y)) + geom_bar()
p3 <- ggplot(data.frame(x=c("a","b","c"),y=c("Crazy happy","sad","Just follow the flow")),aes(x=factor(0),fill=y)) + geom_bar()

grid.arrange(p1, p2, p3, ncol = 1)

same.size.ggplot(c("p1", "p2", "p3"), "p2") # same as same.size.ggplot(c("p2", "p3"), "p1") 

grid.arrange(p1, p2, p3, ncol = 1)
```

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the [patchwork](https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/)-package for that:

```r
require(ggplot2)
require(patchwork)
# data
df = data.frame(x = c("a", "b", "c"),
                y = c("happy", "sad", "ambivalent about life"))
p1 = ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(0), fill=x)) + geom_bar()
p2 = ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(0), fill=y)) + geom_bar()

# Patchwork 1: Does it automatically
p1 / p2

# Patchwork 2: Create a list
l = patchwork::align_patches(p1, p2)
```

Answer (score 0):

As a quick & dirty solution that also works across plots that are not combined into one, you can prepend the legend title with some spaced:

```r
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x=c("a", "b", "c"),
                 y=c("happy", "sad", "ambivalent about life"))
fix_width_lab <- function(lab, width=40) paste0(paste0(rep(" ", width), collapse = ""), "\n", lab)
ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(0), fill=x)) + geom_bar() + labs(fill = fix_width_lab("x"))
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(0), fill=y)) + geom_bar() + labs(fill = fix_width_lab("y"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-11-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>