# consistent plot width in ggplot (not counting labels)

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I automatically and accurately make the width of the plotting area consistent in ggplot, when the labels vary between plots? For example, here are two plots (data and code follow), where the second has longer labels, so the width of the plotting area is made smaller to make room.

I know I can manually make the figure width wider on the second plot, but 1) I can't do that programmatically, and 2) it won't be exact unless I have lots of patience and time.

I don't even know how to search for what I'm calling here "the plotting area", so any assistance even in the terminology is helpful.

[image: first plot is wider]
[image: second plot is narrower]

Here's code to generate the data and plots:

```
set.seed(5)
d1 <- expand.grid(x=LETTERS[1:3], g=letters[1:3], rep=1:10)
d1$y <- round(rnorm(nrow(d1), 10, 2), 1)
d2 <- expand.grid(x=LETTERS[1:3], g=letters[1:3], rep=1:10)
d2$y <- round(rnorm(nrow(d1), 10, 2), 1)
levels(d2$x) <- sapply(levels(d2$x), strrep, 10)
levels(d2$g) <- sapply(levels(d2$g), strrep, 10)

library(ggplot2)
p1 <- ggplot(d1) + aes(x, y, color=g) + geom_boxplot() + coord_flip()
p2 <- ggplot(d2) + aes(x, y, color=g) + geom_boxplot() + coord_flip()
ggsave("test1.pdf", p1)
ggsave("test2.pdf", p2)
```

Comment: there might be some useful alignment tools in `cowplot` ...

Comment: I'm looking into it now, thanks!

Comment: You may look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16255579/how-can-i-make-consistent-width-plots-in-ggplot-with-legends), where the question was already solved

Comment: Nice find, I missed that one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @BenBolker, I'm learning about `cowplot`. It has the `align_plots` function for this purpose (output not shown),

```
both2 <- align_plots(p1, p2, align="hv", axis="tblr")
p1x <- ggdraw(both2[[1]])
p2x <- ggdraw(both2[[2]])
save_plot("cow1.png", p1x)
save_plot("cow2.png", p2x)
```

and also `plot_grid` which saves the plots to the same file.

```
library(cowplot)
both <- plot_grid(p1, p2, ncol=1, labels = c("A", "B"), align = "v")
save_plot("cow.png", both)
```

[image]

I'm still going through cowplot functionality and will add to this answer if I find anything else useful, but if any reader knows of anything else, either in cowplot or not, don't let that stop you from adding another answer!

Comment: Copied information in this answer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/45616684/210673