# R, how to set multiple bar_chart plots to have the same width through grid.arrange?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am generating multiple bar_chart plots in R with ggplot2.
I am using grid.arrange to put them all together in one image.

I would like them to have the same width, but my problem is that their legend labels have different length, and thus they influence the width.

Here's a simplified sample of my code (my code actually has a for loop repeated 10 times):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

i <- 1
plot_list <- list()

var <- c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0)


var2 <- c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0)

P_this <- ggplot(data.frame(var), aes(factor("nothing"), fill=factor(var))) + geom_bar(stat="count", position="stack") +  scale_fill_discrete(labels=c("long title one", "long title two"))

plot_list[[length(plot_list) + 1]] <- P_this

P_this2 <- ggplot(data.frame(var2), aes(factor("nothing"), fill=factor(var))) + geom_bar(stat="count", position="stack") +  scale_fill_discrete(labels=c("women", "men"))

plot_list[[length(plot_list) + 1]] <- P_this2

do.call("grid.arrange", c(plot_list, ncol=1))
dev.off()
```

This code generated this image:
[image]

Please notice that I have to keep the `do.call("grid.arrange", c(plot_list, ncol=1))` command.

**How can I force these two barcharts to have the same width?** 
Thanks!

Comment: `egg::ggarrange(plots=plot_list)` offers an alt.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16255579/how-can-i-make-consistent-width-plots-in-ggplot-with-legends?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Thanks user20650, it worked out! If you have time to write a complete answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: Good stuff Davide, glad it works - I'll mark it as a duplicate, as the link ^^ gives the same solution