# Maintain ggplot panel size while axis labels change length

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I make the panels of separate ggplots align when the y-axis labels change in length across plots? Below I've saved two subsets of mtcars with longer and shorter model names. Although the overall plots are the same size, the panels are smaller in the mt_long plot because the y-axis labels take up more of the plot.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

ds_mt <- mtcars %>% rownames_to_column("model")
mt_short <- ds_mt %>% arrange(nchar(model)) %>% slice(1:4)
mt_long <- ds_mt %>% arrange(-nchar(model)) %>% slice(1:4)

plot_short <- 
    mt_short %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = model, y = mpg)) + 
    geom_col() + 
    coord_flip()

plot_long <- 
    mt_long %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = model, y = mpg)) + 
    geom_col() + 
    coord_flip()

plot_short
plot_long
```

[image]
[image]

For this reprex, it is important that the plots be separate. Is there any way to set just the panel dimensions of the plot rather than the overall size of the plot?

Comment: Is using facets not an option?

Comment: @MauritsEvers no facets are out. This is just a reprex. In reality I need to produce a lot of plots from different datasets and want to control panel size explicitly if that is possible.

Comment: Likely duplicate: [How can I make consistent-width plots in ggplot (with legends)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16255579/how-can-i-make-consistent-width-plots-in-ggplot-with-legends)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `gridarrange` from the `egg` package

```
library(egg)
ggarrange(plot_short, plot_long, ncol = 1)
```

[image]

To save, use

```
gg <- ggarrange(plot_short, plot_long, ncol = 1)
ggsave("file.png", gg)
```

Answer (score 1):

try `egg::set_panel_size(plot_short)`

Comment: Please improve your question little bit more and also demonstrate it

Comment: @user10644264, your code is outputting a table rather than a plot. Is there a way to use set_panel_size with explicit measurements for width and length?