# Align two legends in one plot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, legend

I would like to add legends for two `geom_line` and a `geom_point` at the same time, but the legends were not align to each other. So how to align the two legends and adjust legend positions?  Thank you in advance!

My data:

df1:

```
x1  y1
1   0
2   0
3   0
4   0
5   0
6   0
7   0
8   0
9   0
10  0
11  0
12  0
13  0
14  0
15  0
16  0
17  0
18  0
19  0
20  0
21  0
22  0
23  9.2
24  18.5
25  27.6
26  36.8
27  46.1
28  54.2
29  63.4
30  72.6
31  81.7
32  88.9
33  93
34  99.1
35  105.4
36  110
37  118.3
38  128.2
39  138
40  146.9
41  155.1
42  162.5
43  165.7
44  169.2
45  174.2
46  176.3
47  183.8
48  187.8
49  194.2
50  200.7
51  203.4
52  204.7
53  209.5
54  214.5
55  219.6
56  224.1
57  228.5
58  232.8
59  237
60  239.5
61  242.7
62  243.1
63  244.6
64  245
65  246.6
66  248.6
67  251
68  253
69  255
70  256.7
71  256.7
```

df2:

```
x2  y2
24  0.006525
32  0.072525
39  0.120025
46  0.1601418
53  0.1972939
60  0.2226233
68  0.2312895
```

df3:

```
x3  y3
1   0
2   0
3   0
4   0
5   0
6   0
7   0
8   0
9   0
10  0
11  0
12  0
13  0
14  0
15  0
16  0
17  0
18  0
19  0
20  0
21  0
22  0
23  10.9
24  14.8
25  19.6
26  25.6
27  31.4
28  38.5
29  47.1
30  56.9
31  64.7
32  71
33  77
34  84.7
35  92.5
36  98.8
37  108.2
38  118.8
39  126.9
40  134.3
41  141.1
42  147.2
43  149.9
44  152.8
45  157
46  158.7
47  164.9
48  168.3
49  173.6
50  179
51  181.3
52  182.3
53  186.3
54  190.4
55  194.7
56  198.5
57  202.1
58  205.7
59  209.2
60  211.3
61  213.9
62  214.3
63  215.6
64  215.9
65  217.2
66  218.9
67  220.9
68  222.5
69  224.2
70  225.7
71  225.7
```

My code:

```
library("ggplot2")
library("reshape2")
library("gridExtra")

p <- ggplot() +
  geom_line(data=df1, aes(x= x1, y= y1, linetype= "aa"))+
  geom_point(data=df2, aes(x= x2, y= y2, shape="bbbbbbb"))+
  geom_line(data=df3, aes(x= x3, y= y3, linetype= "cc"))+


  scale_shape_manual(name="",
                      labels=c("bbbbbbb"),
                      values = c(21) )+
  scale_linetype_manual(name="",
                        labels=c("aa","cc"),
                        values=c("solid", "dashed")) +


  ylab("y")+
  xlab("x")+

  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        legend.justification = c(0, 1), 
        legend.position=c(0, 1))
```

My plot:
[image]

Comment: can you `dput` df1, df2 and df3 ?

Comment: Sorry, I can not get the meaning of `dput`, would you please  explain it ? Thank you!

Comment: Add output of `dput(head(df1))`, `dput(head(df1))`, `dput(head(df1))` to the post, so we know more about your data. [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: And add the output of `dput` **inside** your original post and not in comments, please.

Comment: arg ... no the otuput of dput is not a printscreen it's a structure ... copy/paste the imediate result of `dput(head(df1)`

Comment: did you try `legend.position="top"`?

Comment: Try `legend.box.just = "left"` inside `theme()`

Comment: @konvas This method would work, but how to change the space between the upper legend and the lower? Thank you for your reply!

Comment: @MamounBenghezal Thank you for your reply! This method is an alternative, and the next step is to  change the space between the upper legend and the lower.

Comment: @just_rookie If you want to simply remove the excess space between the legends, you can do so by setting the title to `NULL`, e.g. just adding `+ guides(linetype = guide_legend(title = NULL))` to your plot, but if you want to be able to control the xy coordinates of the legends more precisely, this gets complicated (I don't think there is a theme/guides option for it).

Answer (score 2):

Thank you guys for attention. I have find a solution to the problem, I adopted the idea from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13426470/justification-of-multiple-legends-in-ggmap-ggplot2).

```
library("ggplot2")
library("reshape2")
library("gridExtra")
library("gtable")

p <- ggplot() +
  geom_line(data=df1, aes(x= x1, y= y1, linetype= "aa"))+
  geom_point(data=df2, aes(x= x2, y= y2, shape="bbbbbbb"))+
  geom_line(data=df3, aes(x= x3, y= y3, linetype= "cc"))+
  # discard errorbar here.

  scale_shape_manual(name=NULL,
                      labels=c("bbbbbbb"),
                      values = c(21) )+
  scale_linetype_manual(name=NULL,
                        labels=c("aa","cc"),
                        values=c("solid", "dashed")) +


  ylab("y")+
  xlab("x")+

  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        legend.position=c(0, 1),
        legend.justification=c(0,1),
        legend.margin=unit(0,"cm"),
        legend.box="vertical",
        legend.box.just = "left",
        legend.key.size=unit(1,"lines"),
        legend.text.align=0,
        legend.key = element_blank(),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.background=element_blank())

data <- ggplot_build(p)
gtable <- ggplot_gtable(data)
lbox <- which(sapply(gtable$grobs, paste) == "gtable[guide-box]")
guide <- gtable$grobs[[lbox]]
gtable$grobs[[lbox]]$heights <- unit.c(guide$heights[1:2],
                                       unit(-.8,"cm"), 
                                       guide$heights[2:3])
# Plotting
g<-grid.draw(gtable)
```

[image]